# Stored procedure called from form returns duplicate row error, but the record does not exist in table, what's going on?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-express, visual-studio-2019

I am getting the following error when calling a stored procedure from a Windows Form's button click.

[image]

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.User' with unique index 'IX_User_Username'. The duplicate key value is (someusername).

However, my table is empty, so there shouldn't be a duplicate key row error.

The stored procedure does work correctly if I execute it directly from Visual Studio by right-clicking the Stored Procedure and then Execute, I then type in the values and it executes correctly.

I am using

- Visual Studio Community Edition 2019
- SQL Server Express
- .NET 4.7.03190

Here is the User object - this model takes in user's first and last names, username, passwords and handles password hashing and salts.

The `Create()` method inserts calls the stored procedure.

```
public User(String firstName, String lastName, string username, string password)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.username = username;

    Password newPassword = new Password(password);
    newPassword.Hash();

    this.password = newPassword.GetHashedPassword();

    this.salt = newPassword.GetSalt();
    this.loginAttempts = 0;
    this.locked = false;
}

public void Create()
{
    database = new Database();

    using (SqlConnection conn = database.GetSqlConnection())
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CreateUserStoredProcedure", conn))
        {
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", this.firstName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", this.lastName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", this.username);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", this.password);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salt", this.salt);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loginAttempts", this.loginAttempts);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locked", this.locked);

            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    //  returns the result for testing
                    Console.WriteLine("From Reader - ");
                    Console.WriteLine(reader["Return Value"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateUserStoredProcedure]
    @firstName NVARCHAR(50),
    @lastName NVARCHAR(50),
    @username NVARCHAR(50),
    @password NVARCHAR(36),
    @salt NVARCHAR(255),
    @loginAttempts INT = 0,
    @locked BIT = 0
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Id INT

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users]
    VALUES (@username)

    SET @Id = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY])

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[People] (User_Id, FirstName, LastName) 
    VALUES (@Id, @firstName, @lastName)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Credentials] (User_Id, "Password", Salt, LoginAttempts, Locked) 
    VALUES (@Id, @password, @salt, @loginAttempts, @locked)

    RETURN 1
END
```

Table structure is simple:

- User (Id, Username) (Unique Index 'IX_User_Username')
- People (User_Id, FirstName, LastName) (FK User_Id > User.Id)
- Credentials (User_Id, Password, Salt, LoginAttempts, Locked) (FK User_Id > User.ID)

I am expecting the new user to be added from the form, from given input data, just as it does when executing the stored procedure directly.

I have tested in the `Create()` method by using `Console.WriteLine()` for each input data to make sure that I am sending the correct values to the stored procedure. Surely, the username is getting sent correctly:

[image]

Can you help me to determine the issue? Thanks.

EDIT:

Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateUserStoredProcedure]
    @firstName nvarchar(50),
    @lastName nvarchar(50),
    @username nvarchar(50),
    @password nvarchar(36),
    @salt nvarchar(255),
    @loginAttempts int = 0,
    @locked bit = 0

AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        DECLARE
            @Id int

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[User]
        VALUES 
        (@username)

        SET @Id = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY])
        --SET @Id = (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE Username = @username)

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Person] 
        (User_Id, FirstName, LastName) 
        VALUES 
        (@Id, @firstName, @lastName)

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Credential] 
        (User_Id, "Password", Salt, LoginAttempts, Locked) 
        VALUES 
        (@Id, @password, @salt, @loginAttempts, @locked)

        RETURN 1

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF(@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    RAISERROR ('User could not be created', 0, 0);
END CATCH
```

Comment: Is your id being incremented?

Comment: Yes. Identity Specifications is set to true, and incremented by 1.

```CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [Id]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);```

Comment: I would expect that you wanted the latest created ID from users to be used as Id when creating People and credentials. Shouldn't that call Select id from Users  where username = @username to get utilized?

Comment: You are executing the stored procedure twice. `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` and `using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())`. If you want that single return value from the sproc, call `ExecuteScaler()`.

Comment: The Scope_Identity() successfully returns the created Id, and I use that Id to fill in the remaining tables, at least when executing the SP directly. I edited Stored Procedure to use Select Id instead of Scope_Identity and the same issue exist from Win form, but it does work when executing the SP directly. Hmm. That's not the issue.

Comment: Did you read my comment @MichaelBerrios? You are executing it twice.

Comment: @SimonWilson, sorry about that power went out. I read your comment, and that's a good catch. I am embarrassed for not catching that. I commented out ExecuteNonQuery() and left ExecuteReader() only. Now it's not spitting out the duplicate row key error, so that's good. But it's also not inserting records into the table. Tried ExecuteScalar(), but there's no insert.

Comment: I don't think ExecuteReader() is what you want...you're not returning a result set via a SELECT or anything. So when you run this say, `var result = command.ExecuteScaler();` or `var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery()`, what is the value of `result`? The `Create()` method is not wrapped in a Transaction is it?

Comment: The Create() method isn't wrapped in a transaction. ```var result = command.ExecuteScalar();``` yielded nothing. 

When I click the "Create" button once, nothing happens, but if I click it a second time, a duplicate row key error. However, there are no records inserted. 
If I am not mistaken, because SQL is transaction based database, I must commit a transaction. 

So I edited my stored procedure (see edit) around a transaction. And got the following:

"Transaction count after Execute indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1."

Comment: Try moving your `COMMIT TRANSACTION` above the `RETURN` statement.

Comment: @SimonWilson I will try that out later today. Will let you know. The SQLExpress provided within Visual Studio is problematic (disconnections, files not found, etc). So I went ahead and installed the stand alone SQL Server Express stand alone, which is more stable and reliable to have it separate from code.

Comment: @SimonWilson, I moved the ```Commit Transaction``` above the ```RETURN``` statement, and now the Stored Procedure is working as expected. This makes sense. Thank you. I am now able to insert records.